# Change input type on Stack Exchange Login Page

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, login, openid

I'm being incredibly picky but since I don't have access to the Stack Exchange App yet and I often browse Stack Overflow from my phone, I think it would be useful to change the email input type from `text` to the new HTML5 [`email`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.email.html#input.email) type on the [Stack Exchange Login Page](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login). Small but useful change!

The benefit of doing this is:

> The input element with a type attribute whose value is "email"
>   represents a control for editing a list of e-mail addresses given in
>   the element’s value

Here is a visual example:

[image]

It provides some convenient keys on a phone to be able to type an email address quickly without having to scroll through the symbols.

Comment: Luckily, I have the Stack Exchange app. But I support this request. Voted up! :)